# How to filter by some column in bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a table with one column called gender, and only have two values: male and female.

What I want is a select above the table, when I select male, only rows with gender column equals to male shows.

How to do it in bootstrap-table? cannot find any similiar examples.

Comment: Can you use a plugin called Datatables? you will get everything you want with a single line of code. But if you want to write a custom logic then let us know

Comment: Are you using AngularJs?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use DataTables, it has everything: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
         if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
     }       
   }
}
```

In the code that w3schools provided [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) the only thing that you need is to change the number in the `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];` to the number of the column that you need.